# Bootstrap toggable tabs not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Good afternoon everyone. Been working on this for a week and have had no success. This is probably a newbie javascript mistake but I do not know the JS language yet, only HTML+CSS. Thanks for any assistance.

The content is not changing when I click on my tabs. Here's my code:

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

...

```
<div class="tabbable">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Hunts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Great Outdoors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Instructional</a></li>
          </ul>


        <div class="tab-content">
              <ul id="tab1" class="tab-pane active"class='videolist'>
                    <li class='videolist'><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="50" id="player" mozallowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/67860856" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="100"></iframe><span class='vidtext'>ddddddddddddddddddddddd99999</span></li>
                    <li class='videolist'><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="50" id="player" mozallowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/66467447" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="100"></iframe><span class='vidtext'>ddddddddddddddddddddddd99999</span></li>
                    <li class='videolist'><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="50" id="player" mozallowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65989351" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="100"></iframe><span class='vidtext'>dsfdfsdfsdfsdf</span></li>
                    <li class='videolist'><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="50" id="player" mozallowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65442532" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="100"></iframe><span class='vidtext'>ddddddddddddddddddddddd99999</span></li>
                    <li class='videolist'><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="50" id="player" mozallowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/64932895" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="100"></iframe><span class='vidtext'>dsfdfsdfsdfsdf</span></li>
                    <li class='videolist'><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="50" id="player" mozallowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/64120939" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="100"></iframe><span class='vidtext'>ddddddddddddddddddddddd99999</span></li>
                    <li class='videolist'><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="50" id="player" mozallowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/64028154" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="100"></iframe><span class='vidtext'>dsfdfsdfsdfsdf</span></li>
                    <li class='videolist'><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="50" id="player" mozallowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/63489842" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="100"></iframe><span class='vidtext'>ddddddddddddddddddddddd99999</span></li>
                    <li class='videolist'><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="50" id="player" mozallowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/60358260" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="100"></iframe><span class='vidtext'>dsfdfsdfsdfsdf</span></li>
              </ul>
        </div>

  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane" >
  <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">
  <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 3.</p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.7");</script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </script>    

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following HTML will cause the tabs to work properly and the content to be changed.

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Hunts</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Great Outdoors</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Instructional</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
            <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 1.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
            <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 2.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane">
            <p>Howdy, I'm in Section 3.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then just change the content in the divs to whatever you require.

A working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/SOFiddles/ZcgSc/

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose `ul` inside these tags and remove `id`, `tab-pane` & `active` classes from `ul`

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active"> 
<ul>
    <li class='videolist'>
         <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="50" id="player" mozallowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/67860856" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="100"></iframe>
         <span class='vidtext'>ddddddddddddddddddddddd99999</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6240/)**